# WordPress issue with stick posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using sticky posts to allow certain posts to be pinned in a featured post area. I have it working on a development server but when I moved it to the live server it only partially works. If there is a sticky post it displays it. But if there isn't a sticky post it displays nothing and it should display the most recent post. Is there an alternate way to handle this that may work?

```
$options = array(
    'post_type' => post,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'status' => 'publish'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check result of `get_option( 'sticky_posts' )` first:

```
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
if ( !empty($sticky) ) {
   // query options for sticky posts
   $options = array(
       'post_type' => post,
       'posts_per_page' => 1,
       'post__in'  => $sticky,
       'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
       'status' => 'publish'
   );
} else {
    // query options for the most recent post
    $options = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'paged' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
}
```